# Javascript objects: use a variable's value to access a specific object

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic

I have multiple objects with identical properties:

```
var obj1 = { bar: "value1", foo: "value2"};
var obj2 = { bar: "value3", foo: "value4"};
```

I also have a variable.

```
var selector = "";
```

`selector` is either "obj1" or "obj2".
How can I call one of the objects using `selector` without knowing the object's name?

For instance, I tried:

```
window(["selector"][bar])
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: `window[selector].bar`

Comment: But you probably shouldn't be doing that; have `obj1` and `obj2` themselves be properties of one of your own objects rather than the global object.

Comment: In addition to what @Pointy said, the reason here is that () are used to invoke a method, so by doing `window()` your script looks for a function called window

Comment: or just use lodash with it's `_.get` method that will safely return undefined or default value. example: `_.get(window, 'obj1.foo')` or `_.get(window, 'obj1.baar', null)` or `var selector = 'obj1.foo'; var value = _.get(window, selector);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have parenthesis. *window* is not a function. Try without the parenthesis. In addition, you need to put quotes around *bar*.

```
window[selector]["bar"]
```